# pip install unable to build wheel for scrypt and pyethash

Tags: django, pip, python-wheel, web3py

I tried to install django-web3-auth with all the commands described in the official documentation `pip install django-web3-auth` and also tryied from github `https://github.com/Bearle/django-web3-auth/archive/master.zip` and `pip install https://github.com/atereshkin/django-web3-auth/archive/master.zip` but I always get the same error `Building wheel for scrypt (setup.py) ... error`... `ERROR: Failed building wheel for scrypt`, `Building wheel for pyethash (setup.py)` ... `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyethash`. I am obsessed and desperate now.
i'm on windows 10. I've already tried with all the ways I've read in blogs like use `--no-cache-dir`, 
but not work. I will love and be eternally grateful to anyone who can help me.
i can't sleep with this problem in my head.

Comment: Your question does not include the full build log, which probably will contain a helpful error message hinting that you do not have some of the required dependencies installed on your computer. Please edit the question and add full install logs.